# How to return several rows from regexp_substr

Tags: regex, oracle

I have regex expression like this (used in oracle database):

```
with rws as (
  select '143,3344,40099' str from dual
)
  select regexp_substr (
           '143,3344,40099',
           '^\d+(,\d+)*$',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <=
    length ( str ) - length (replace (str, ',' )) + 1;
```

I don't understand why it's returning only one row:

[image]

and the other two rows are empty?
I would like to return one row for each number.

Answer (score 3):

That's because query (you used in CONNECT BY clause) results in 3 rows:

```
SQL> with rws as (
  2    select '143,3344,40099' str from dual
  3  )
  4  select length ( str ) - length (replace (str, ',' )) + 1
  5  from rws;

LENGTH(STR)-LENGTH(REPLACE(STR,','))+1
--------------------------------------
                                     3

SQL>
```

That's something similar to *hardcoded* `3` in CONNECT BY:

```
SQL> select 'x'
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 3;

'
-
x          --> 3 rows, as you can see
x
x

SQL>
```

Therefore, the *whole* query returns what it is told to: 3 rows, but only one has value due to wrong regular expression: `'^\d+(,\d+)*$'`; you want just `'\d+'`.

I guess you're actually looking for

```
SQL> with rws as (
  2    select '143,3344,40099' str from dual
  3  )
  4    select regexp_substr (str, '\d+', 1, level) value
  5    from   rws
  6    connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ',') + 1;

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------
143
3344
40099

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `regexp_substr` with the following parameters:

```
regexp_substr (
           '143,3344,40099',
           '^\d+(,\d+)*$',
           1,
           level
         )
```

so for `Level = 1` it is matching the first occurrence of the pattern which is any number and comma and again number so in your case entire string `'143,3344,40099'` matches the pattern `'^\d+(,\d+)*$'`.
Now, for second and third row `regexp_Substr` is unable to find the second and third occurrence of the same pattern so they are `NULL`.

Instead you can use to avoid any commas in the pattern to match with any value except commas --> `'[^,]+'` as follows:

```
with rws as (
  select '143,3344,40099' str from dual
)
  select regexp_substr (
           '143,3344,40099',
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <=
    length ( str ) - length (replace (str, ',' )) + 1;
```